# Copy two parts of a string to two other strings using strncpy

Tags: c, c-strings, strncpy

I want to copy two parts of string s to two strings a and b:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   char s[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
   char a[10];
   char b[6];
   strncpy( a, s, 10 );
   a[10] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n", a);
   strncpy( b, s+10, 6 );
   b[6] = '\0';
   printf("%s  %s\n", a, b);
   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0123456789
  ABCDEF
```

I had expected

```
0123456789
0123456789  ABCDEF
```

What has happened to a? Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: `a[10] = '\0';` and `b[6] = '\0';` are invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays a and b do not contain strings. Declare them like

```
char a[11];
char b[7];
```

that is reserve one more element for the terminating zero character.

Otherwise these statements

```
a[10] = '\0';
b[6] = '\0';
```

use invalid indices.